# How to run java project Automatically every XX hours

Tags: java

I have a java project with GUI interface(in eclipse).
I want to be able to run this project, edit few options in the interface, close it some point, and then do the whole cycle again after few hours.

Is it possible to write a program that will start other program, and click it's buttons?
I have no idea where to start, will be to some guide lines

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Running a "console" app in Windows is a simple matter of using Task Scheduler.  The GUI makes it more complicated.  Consider making a non-GUI version of your app.

Comment: Use crontab (Linux) or AT (windows)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. The detail depends on your operating system, among other things. Here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools is a list of tools which will automatically operate your program by "clicking it's buttons"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com) ? Or Powershell ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/),a simple cron api for Java

Comment: Can I click on some buttons in the UI with Quartz?

Comment: no;it's a java program that you may write by yourself to schedule it

Comment: If you need a GUI for Quartz, you can use QuartzDesk or an alternative product that allows you to remotely connect to your Quartz scheduler instance and manage it.